# how to avoid the dependency project entity table creation in Spring jpa DATA?

Tags: spring

i am having A project with Entity called Employee.java.its creates the employee table in XYZschema.

I have another project B with entity called department.java.Its creates the department table in ABC schema.

Now am adding project A as dependency to project B.but now both employee and department tables get created in ABC schema.

How to avoid employee table creation in schema ABC?

Comment: Can you show some Code, e.g. Spring Configuration?

Comment: remove `hibernate.ddl.auto`  or set to `validate`

Comment: hibernate.ddl.auto will be applied to all entities scanning with @Entity annotation. It is not possible to create only one entity.

Comment: @Antoniossss..adding validate throws error " Schema-validation: missing table [xyz.employee]"

Comment: @CRISTIAN ROMERO MATESANZ..okay.Is there a way, can we exclude those entity?

Answer (score 0):

if you use:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.youpackage"} )
```

change your class to another package outside this route. 
(com.anotherpackage) and your @entity won't be scanned by Spring boot.